# Add or Replace Widget Icon in WordPress Customizer API

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add icons but haven't any success can anyone.

[image: Add icon and title in widget]

I used below code

```
public function __construct() {
parent::__construct(
    'mytheme_block_posts_widget',
    'Block Posts',  
    array(
        'classname' => 'widget_authors',
        'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
        'description' => 'A widget to display latest posts Block with options.',
    )
);

// Define your widget's icon class
$this->widget_icon = 'dashicons-admin-post'; // Replace with the appropriate icon class
}
```

How to add Icons and widgets under a custom category like text or any. If anyone knows please suggest.